# IOS Admob interstitial on button click?

Tags: ios, admob, ads, interstitial

Interstitial is showing just once after fourth click. Can someone do it to show for example on every click I want (on 10 th click, on 20 th click...)

```
if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
    if (count > 4){
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
        count = 0;
    }
}
count += 1;
```

Comment: After `interstitial` dismissed, you have to create a new `interstitial` for next time

Comment: Thank you but can you write the example code how to show interstitial click after click(example when I click it for the 4th time, 6th time, 20th time...).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
    [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

### Delete Conditions

```
- (GADInterstitial *)createAndLoadInterstitial
{
    GADInterstitial *interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-yourAdId";
    interstitial.delegate = self;
    [interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    return interstitial;
}
```

Please get this method on application launch, then you can set follow method for many time everywhere:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if ([appDelegate.interstitial isReady]) {
    [appDelegate.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: Its ok with interstitial it is shown when the button is clicked, but I want on click after click to be shown, example when I click it for the 4th time, 6th time, 20th time...